# Dynamic Input for same chart updating

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a chart that will update its values automatically as time goes. The Y values of the data are constant while the X values are changing with time. My data is as follows:

```
               Y data = 1    1.5     2    2.5      3
At time = 0    X data = 10   10     10    10       10
At time = 0.5  X data = 20   20     20    20       20
At time = 1.0  X data = 30   30     30    30       30
At time = 1.5  X data = 40   40     40    40       40
```

***NOTE MY X DATA ARE NOT CONSECUTIVE, THEY ARE IN 5 COLUMNS AS SHOWN ABOVE BUT NOT CONSECUTIVE COLUMNS.**

This is what I have reached until now

```
Sub UpdateChart()
    Dim ChtObj As ChartObject
    Dim BM1 As Range, BM2 As Range, BM3 As Range, BM4 As Range, BM5 As Range

Set ChtObj = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(200, 150, 500, 500)

'Creating intial graph
With ChtObj.Chart
    'Chart Type
    .ChartType = xlXYScatterSmooth

    'Datainput
    .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    .SeriesCollection(1).Name = "Bending moment"
    .SeriesCollection(1).Values = Range("D3:H3")
    ''How to do this .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = Range((Cells(5, 4), Cells(5, 6), Cells(5, 8), Cells(5, 10), Cells(5, 12))
    .HasLegend = False

    'Title
    .HasTitle = True
    .ChartTitle.Text = "Bending moment along pile " & ActiveSheet.Name

    'X-Axis
    .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
    .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Bending moment (kN.m)"
    'Y-Axis
    .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
    .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Length along pile (m)"

End With

'Loopingthrough data to be done**

End Sub
```

How can I enter the X data using Cells() function so I can incorporate that into the loop? 
Your help is greatly appreciated!

**My X data are not in continuous**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add a discontinuous range from the active sheet use

```
.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = Application.Union(Cells(5, 4), Cells(5, 6), Cells(5, 8), Cells(5, 10), Cells(5, 12))
```

Comment: Thank you so much!